# Squeezing decorators into functional extensions

Tags: c#, design-patterns, comparative-review, extension-methods

When you try to use several decorators it can get *ugly* pretty quickly and you'll end up with:

> ```
> new RelativeFileProvider(
>   new SystemVariableFileProvider(
>       new PhysicalFileProvider()
>   ),
>   "%TEMP%"
> );
> ```

or if you prefer one-liners then like that:

> ```
> new RelativeFileProvider(new SystemVariableFileProvider(new PhysicalFileProvider()), "%TEMP%");
> ```

I thought I turn them into extensions and make them play along nicer in a functional way so I created a couple of helper methods that allow me to do this:

```
new PhysicalFileProvider()      
    .DecorateWith(SystemVariableFileProvider.Create())
    .DecorateWith(RelativeFileProvider.Create("%TEMP%"));
```

Don't be confused about the empty classes. To be able to experiment without being distracted by the implementations I extracted the interface and the classes from my question about [Multiple file access abstractions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/207585/multiple-file-access-abstractions)
 that I'm going to use this *pattern* for. They all have implementations that have been already reviewed there. This question is about the additional *decorator helper* APIs and they are implementation-netural.

Here are the types I used:

#### Version 1 - with an exntesion

```
interface IFileProvider
{

}

class PhysicalFileProvider : IFileProvider
{
    public static PhysicalFileProvider Create()
    {
        return new PhysicalFileProvider();
    }
}

class RelativeFileProvider : IFileProvider
{
    public RelativeFileProvider(IFileProvider fileProvider, string basePath)
    {

    }

    public static Func<IFileProvider, RelativeFileProvider> Create(string basePath)
    {
        return decorable => new RelativeFileProvider(decorable, basePath);
    }
}

class SystemVariableFileProvider : IFileProvider
{
    public SystemVariableFileProvider(IFileProvider fileProvider)
    {

    }

    public static Func<IFileProvider, SystemVariableFileProvider> Create()
    {
        return decorable => new SystemVariableFileProvider(decorable);
    }
}

static class FileProviderExtensions
{
    public static IFileProvider DecorateWith(this IFileProvider decorable, Func<IFileProvider, IFileProvider> createDecorator)
    {
        return createDecorator(decorable);
    }
}
```

---

#### Version 2 - with an interface

This API forces each type to implement the `DecorateWith` method instead of relying on an extension.

```
interface IDecorable<T>
{
    T DecorateWith(Func<T, T> createDecorator); 
}

interface IFileProvider : IDecorable<IFileProvider>
{

}

class PhysicalFileProvider : IFileProvider, IDecorable<IFileProvider>
{
    public static PhysicalFileProvider Create()
    {
        return new PhysicalFileProvider();
    }

    public IFileProvider DecorateWith(Func<IFileProvider, IFileProvider> createDecorator)
    {
        return createDecorator(this);
    }
}

class RelativeFileProvider : IFileProvider, IDecorable<IFileProvider>
{
    public RelativeFileProvider(IFileProvider fileProvider, string basePath)
    {

    }

    public static Func<IFileProvider, RelativeFileProvider> Create(string basePath)
    {
        return decorable => new RelativeFileProvider(decorable, basePath);
    }

    public IFileProvider DecorateWith(Func<IFileProvider, IFileProvider> createDecorator)
    {
        return createDecorator(this);
    }
}

class SystemVariableFileProvider : IFileProvider, IDecorable<IFileProvider>
{
    public SystemVariableFileProvider(IFileProvider fileProvider)
    {

    }

    public static Func<IFileProvider, SystemVariableFileProvider> Create()
    {
        return decorable => new SystemVariableFileProvider(decorable);
    }

    public IFileProvider DecorateWith(Func<IFileProvider, IFileProvider> createDecorator)
    {
        return createDecorator(this);
    }
}
```

---

And these are the **why**s about the factories:

- I chose static factory methods over *free* arguments to keep parameter names and their order.
- I chose them also to avoid `new`.

---

What do you think of this *system*? Do you prefer one version over the other? Can this be made even more convinient? Or would you say this is madness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO the first version is easier to maintain, and I don't see from the shown code, what you gain by the second.

---

In the second version:

Each `FileProvider` class doesn't need to explicitly inherit `IDecorable<IFileProvider>` because that is inherited via `IFileProvider`.

---

I maybe overlooking something or you may find it too obvious to show, but I don't like that you implement the interface `IFileProvider` in all the provider classes, because they then are forced to implement all (I can see there aren't any (yet)) possible common members, which could be taken care of in a base class. Therefore I would create an abstract base class for the providers like:

```
  interface IDecorable<T>
  {
    T DecorateWith(Func<T, T> createDecorator);
  }

  interface IFileProvider : IDecorable<IFileProvider>
  {

  }

  abstract class FileProvider : IFileProvider
  {
    public virtual IFileProvider DecorateWith(Func<IFileProvider, IFileProvider> createDecorator)
    {
      return createDecorator(this);
    }
  }

  class PhysicalFileProvider : FileProvider
  {
    public static PhysicalFileProvider Create()
    {
      return new PhysicalFileProvider();
    }
  }

  class RelativeFileProvider : FileProvider
  {
    public RelativeFileProvider(IFileProvider fileProvider, string basePath)
    {

    }

    public static Func<IFileProvider, RelativeFileProvider> Create(string basePath)
    {
      return decorable => new RelativeFileProvider(decorable, basePath);
    }
  }
  ...
```

In this way you gain both the benefits of normal OOP inheritance/polymorphic behavior and the decorator pattern and at the same time are still free to chain `.DecorateWith(...)` with other implementers of `IFileProvider`

---

Madness is a strong word. The shown chain looks a little nicer than a chain of `new xx()` statements, and you explicitly "explain" the pattern and behavior. And the first version doesn't need much attention when first written, so no harm done at least.