# One interface for multiple CRUD resources

Tags: c#, api, io, dependency-injection, framework

I asked about an abstraction layer for accessing files ([link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/207585/multiple-file-access-abstractions)) a couple of days ago (I decided to not call it a follow-up anymore as there are too many changes). I tried to incorporate many of the ideas from the feedbacks but it wasn't easy. In the meantime I noticed that what I'm actually doing is nothing else but [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) so by implementing this *pattern* I was able to solve a lot more problems that I initially intended to. I think I now have found *THE* API that is consistent, flexible and allows to work with various kinds of *resources*; and it's also dependency-injection-friendly.

The idea for the new API is inspired by REST and specifically by [HTTP verbs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods): `GET`, `PUT`, `POST`, `DELETE` and that resources are being accessed by some *name*.

```
[PublicAPI]
public interface IResourceProvider
{
    [NotNull]
    ResourceMetadata Metadata { get; }

    [ItemNotNull]
    Task<IResourceInfo> GetAsync([NotNull] UriString uri, ResourceMetadata metadata = null);

    [ItemNotNull]
    Task<IResourceInfo> PostAsync([NotNull] UriString uri, [NotNull] Stream value, ResourceMetadata metadata = null);

    [ItemNotNull]
    Task<IResourceInfo> PutAsync([NotNull] UriString uri, [NotNull] Stream value, ResourceMetadata metadata = null);

    [ItemNotNull]
    Task<IResourceInfo> DeleteAsync([NotNull] UriString uri, ResourceMetadata metadata = null);
}
```

This main interface is pretty generic so that I can use it with different resources. The `IResourceInfo` that each method returns is defined as:

```
[PublicAPI]
public interface IResourceInfo : IEquatable<IResourceInfo>, IEquatable<string>
{
    [NotNull]
    UriString Uri { get; }

    bool Exists { get; }

    long? Length { get; }

    DateTime? CreatedOn { get; }

    DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; }

    Task CopyToAsync(Stream stream);

    Task<object> DeserializeAsync(Type targetType);
}
```

and provides basic information about the resource.

Resources are identified by my `UriString`. I use it as replacement for `Uri`. *(I asked about it [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/209777/replacing-uri-with-a-more-convenient-class) where it was called `SimpleUri`.)*

`ResourceMetadata` is just a wrapper around the `IImmutableDictionary`

```
public class ResourceMetadata
{
    private readonly IImmutableDictionary<SoftString, object> _metadata;

    private ResourceMetadata(IImmutableDictionary<SoftString, object> metadata) => _metadata = metadata;

    public static ResourceMetadata Empty => new ResourceMetadata(ImmutableDictionary<SoftString, object>.Empty);

    public object this[SoftString key] => _metadata[key];
    public int Count => _metadata.Count;
    public IEnumerable<SoftString> Keys => _metadata.Keys;
    public IEnumerable<object> Values => _metadata.Values;
    public bool ContainsKey(SoftString key) => _metadata.ContainsKey(key);
    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<SoftString, object> pair) => _metadata.Contains(pair);
    public bool TryGetKey(SoftString equalKey, out SoftString actualKey) => _metadata.TryGetKey(equalKey, out actualKey);
    public bool TryGetValue(SoftString key, out object value) => _metadata.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    public ResourceMetadata Add(SoftString key, object value) => new ResourceMetadata(_metadata.Add(key, value));
    public ResourceMetadata SetItem(SoftString key, object value) => new ResourceMetadata(_metadata.SetItem(key, value));
}
```

Its purpose is to carry additional information about the *request* (like a specific resource-provider name) or resource-provider *abbilities* or other metadata:

```
public static class ResourceMetadataKeys
{
    public static string ProviderDefaultName { get; } = nameof(ProviderDefaultName);
    public static string ProviderCustomName { get; } = nameof(ProviderCustomName);
    public static string CanGet { get; } = nameof(CanGet);
    public static string CanPost { get; } = nameof(CanPost);
    public static string CanPut { get; } = nameof(CanPut);
    public static string CanDelete { get; } = nameof(CanDelete);
    public static string Scheme { get; } = nameof(Scheme);
    public static string Serializer { get; } = nameof(Serializer);
    public static string AllowRelativeUri { get; } = nameof(AllowRelativeUri);
}
```

Each of these interfaces have an `abstract` implementation. Their purpose is provide general parameter validation and to wrap inner exceptions in exceptions adding information about the resource-provider and the request. This is useful for debugging and helps to reduce error-handling in concrete types. This also specifies a `DefaultScheme` which is `ionymous`. It means that the *scheme* part is irrelevant and should be ignored. This is used by the `CompositeResourceProvider` that can look for a resource in several places. Otherwise *scheme* matters.

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{DebuggerDisplay,nq}")]
public abstract class ResourceProvider : IResourceProvider
{
    public static readonly string DefaultScheme = "ionymous";

    protected ResourceProvider(ResourceMetadata metadata)
    {
        if (!metadata.ContainsKey(ResourceMetadataKeys.Scheme)) throw new ArgumentException(paramName: nameof(metadata), message: $"Resource provider metadata must specify the scheme.");

        // If this is a decorator then the decorated resource-provider already has set this.
        if (!metadata.ContainsKey(ProviderDefaultName))
        {
            metadata = metadata.Add(ProviderDefaultName, GetType().ToPrettyString());
        }

        Metadata = metadata;
    }

    private string DebuggerDisplay => this.ToDebuggerDisplayString(builder =>
    {            
        builder.DisplayCollection(x => x.Metadata.ProviderNames());
        builder.DisplayMember(x => x.Scheme);
    });

    public virtual ResourceMetadata Metadata { get; }

    public virtual SoftString Scheme => (SoftString)(string)Metadata[ResourceMetadataKeys.Scheme];

    #region Wrappers

    // These wrappers are to provide helpful exceptions.

    public async Task<IResourceInfo> GetAsync(UriString uri, ResourceMetadata metadata = null)
    {
        ValidateCanMethod();
        ValidateSchemeNotEmpty(uri);
        ValidateSchemeMatches(uri);

        try
        {
            return await GetAsyncInternal(uri, metadata);
        }
        catch (Exception inner)
        {
            throw CreateException(uri, metadata, inner);
        }
    }

    public async Task<IResourceInfo> PostAsync(UriString uri, Stream value, ResourceMetadata metadata = null)
    {
        ValidateCanMethod();
        ValidateSchemeNotEmpty(uri);
        ValidateSchemeMatches(uri);

        try
        {
            return await PostAsyncInternal(uri, value, metadata);
        }
        catch (Exception inner)
        {
            throw CreateException(uri, metadata, inner);
        }
    }

    public async Task<IResourceInfo> PutAsync(UriString uri, Stream value, ResourceMetadata metadata = null)
    {
        ValidateCanMethod();
        ValidateSchemeNotEmpty(uri);
        ValidateSchemeMatches(uri);

        try
        {
            return await PutAsyncInternal(uri, value, metadata);
        }
        catch (Exception inner)
        {
            throw CreateException(uri, metadata, inner);
        }
    }

    public async Task<IResourceInfo> DeleteAsync(UriString uri, ResourceMetadata metadata = null)
    {
        ValidateCanMethod();
        ValidateSchemeNotEmpty(uri);
        ValidateSchemeMatches(uri);

        try
        {
            return await DeleteAsyncInternal(uri, metadata);
        }
        catch (Exception inner)
        {
            throw CreateException(uri, metadata, inner);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Internal

    protected virtual Task<IResourceInfo> GetAsyncInternal(UriString uri, ResourceMetadata metadata = null) => throw new NotSupportedException();

    protected virtual Task<IResourceInfo> PostAsyncInternal(UriString uri, Stream value, ResourceMetadata metadata = null) => throw new NotSupportedException();

    protected virtual Task<IResourceInfo> PutAsyncInternal(UriString uri, Stream value, ResourceMetadata metadata = null) => throw new NotSupportedException();

    protected virtual Task<IResourceInfo> DeleteAsyncInternal(UriString uri, ResourceMetadata metadata = null) => throw new NotSupportedException();

    #endregion

    #region Helpers

    protected Exception CreateException(UriString uri, ResourceMetadata metadata, Exception inner, [CallerMemberName] string memberName = null)
    {
        // ReSharper disable once AssignNullToNotNullAttribute
        var method = Regex.Replace(memberName, "Async$", string.Empty).ToUpper();

        throw DynamicException.Create
        (
            memberName,
            $"{GetType().ToPrettyString()} was unable to perform {method} for the given resource '{uri}'.",
            inner
        );
    }

    #endregion

    #region Validations

    protected void ValidateSchemeMatches([NotNull] UriString uri)
    {
        if (Metadata.TryGetValue(AllowRelativeUri, out bool allow) && allow)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (SoftString.Comparer.Equals(Scheme, DefaultScheme))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!SoftString.Comparer.Equals(uri.Scheme, Scheme))
        {
            throw DynamicException.Create
            (
                "InvalidScheme",
                $"{GetType().ToPrettyString()} requires scheme '{Scheme}'."
            );
        }
    }

    protected void ValidateCanMethod([CallerMemberName] string memberName = null)
    {
        // ReSharper disable once AssignNullToNotNullAttribute
        var method = Regex.Replace(memberName, "Async$", string.Empty);

        if (!Metadata.TryGetValue($"Can{method}", out bool can) || !can)
        {
            throw DynamicException.Create
            (
                $"{method}NotSupported",
                $"{GetType().ToPrettyString()} doesn't support '{method.ToUpper()}'."
            );
        }
    }

    protected void ValidateSchemeNotEmpty([NotNull] UriString uri)
    {
        if (Metadata.TryGetValue(AllowRelativeUri, out bool allow) && allow)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!uri.Scheme)
        {
            throw DynamicException.Create("SchemeNotFound", $"Uri '{uri}' does not contain scheme.");
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

`ResourceInfo` is implemented as following:

```
[PublicAPI]
[DebuggerDisplay("{DebuggerDisplay,nq}")]
public abstract class ResourceInfo : IResourceInfo
{
    protected ResourceInfo([NotNull] UriString uri)
    {
        if (uri == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(uri));

        Uri = uri.IsRelative ? new UriString($"{ResourceProvider.DefaultScheme}:{uri}") : uri;
    }

    private string DebuggerDisplay => this.ToDebuggerDisplayString(builder =>
    {
        builder.DisplayMember(x => x.Uri);
        builder.DisplayMember(x => x.Exists);
    });

    #region IResourceInfo

    public virtual UriString Uri { get; }

    public abstract bool Exists { get; }

    public abstract long? Length { get; }

    public abstract DateTime? CreatedOn { get; }

    public abstract DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; }

    #endregion

    #region Wrappers

    // These wrappers are to provide helpful exceptions.

    public async Task CopyToAsync(Stream stream)
    {
        AssertExists();

        try
        {
            await CopyToAsyncInternal(stream);
        }
        catch (Exception inner)
        {
            throw DynamicException.Create
            (
                $"{nameof(CopyToAsync)}",
                $"Affected resource '{Uri}'.",
                inner
            );
        }
    }

    public async Task<object> DeserializeAsync(Type targetType)
    {
        AssertExists();

        try
        {
            return await DeserializeAsyncInternal(targetType);
        }
        catch (Exception inner)
        {
            throw DynamicException.Create
            (
                $"{nameof(DeserializeAsync)}",
                $"Affected resource '{Uri}'.",
                inner
            );
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Internal

    protected abstract Task CopyToAsyncInternal(Stream stream);

    protected abstract Task<object> DeserializeAsyncInternal(Type targetType);

    #endregion

    #region IEquatable<IResourceInfo>

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is IResourceInfo resource && Equals(resource);

    public bool Equals(IResourceInfo other) => ResourceInfoEqualityComparer.Default.Equals(other, this);

    public bool Equals(string other) => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(other) && ResourceInfoEqualityComparer.Default.Equals((UriString)other, Uri);

    public override int GetHashCode() => ResourceInfoEqualityComparer.Default.GetHashCode(this);

    #endregion

    #region Helpers

    protected void AssertExists([CallerMemberName] string memberName = null)
    {
        if (!Exists)
        {
            // ReSharper disable once AssignNullToNotNullAttribute
            throw DynamicException.Create(memberName, $"Resource '{Uri}' does not exist.");
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

#### Example

As an example let me show you one of my many new resource-providers, the `AppSettingProvider`:

```
public class AppSettingProvider : ResourceProvider
{
    private readonly ITypeConverter _uriStringToSettingIdentifierConverter;

    public AppSettingProvider(ITypeConverter uriStringToSettingIdentifierConverter = null)
        : base(
            ResourceMetadata.Empty
                .Add(ResourceMetadataKeys.CanGet, true)
                .Add(ResourceMetadataKeys.CanPut, true)
                .Add(ResourceMetadataKeys.Scheme, "setting")
        )
    {
        _uriStringToSettingIdentifierConverter = uriStringToSettingIdentifierConverter;
    }

    protected override Task<IResourceInfo> GetAsyncInternal(UriString uri, ResourceMetadata metadata = null)
    {
        var settingIdentifier = (string)_uriStringToSettingIdentifierConverter?.Convert(uri, typeof(string)) ?? uri;
        var exeConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        var actualKey = FindActualKey(exeConfig, settingIdentifier) ?? settingIdentifier;
        var element = exeConfig.AppSettings.Settings[actualKey];
        return Task.FromResult<IResourceInfo>(new AppSettingInfo(uri, element?.Value));
    }

    protected override async Task<IResourceInfo> PutAsyncInternal(UriString uri, Stream stream, ResourceMetadata metadata = null)
    {
        using (var valueReader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            var value = await valueReader.ReadToEndAsync();

            var settingIdentifier = (string)_uriStringToSettingIdentifierConverter?.Convert(uri, typeof(string)) ?? uri;
            var exeConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            var actualKey = FindActualKey(exeConfig, settingIdentifier) ?? settingIdentifier;
            var element = exeConfig.AppSettings.Settings[actualKey];

            if (element is null)
            {
                exeConfig.AppSettings.Settings.Add(settingIdentifier, value);
            }
            else
            {
                exeConfig.AppSettings.Settings[actualKey].Value = value;
            }

            exeConfig.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal);

            return await GetAsync(uri);
        }
    }

    [CanBeNull]
    private static string FindActualKey(Configuration exeConfig, string key)
    {
        return
            exeConfig
                .AppSettings
                .Settings
                .AllKeys
                .FirstOrDefault(k => SoftString.Comparer.Equals(k, key));
    }
}

internal class AppSettingInfo : ResourceInfo
{
    [CanBeNull] 
    private readonly string _value;

    internal AppSettingInfo([NotNull] UriString uri, [CanBeNull] string value) : base(uri)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public override bool Exists => !(_value is null);

    public override long? Length => _value?.Length;

    public override DateTime? CreatedOn { get; }

    public override DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; }

    protected override async Task CopyToAsyncInternal(Stream stream)
    {        
        // ReSharper disable once AssignNullToNotNullAttribute - this isn't null here
        using (var valueStream = _value.ToStreamReader())
        {
            await valueStream.BaseStream.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }
    }

    protected override Task<object> DeserializeAsyncInternal(Type targetType)
    {         
        return Task.FromResult<object>(_value);
    }
}
```

Other types that I've needed and implemented so far, are:

- `AppSettingProvider` ✓
- `ConnectionStringProvider` ✓
- `PhysicalFileProvider` ✓
- `PhysicalDirectoryProvider` ✓
- `InMemoryResourceProvider` ✓
- `EmbeddedFileProvider` ✓
- `CompositeResourceProvider` ✓ (I use this for accessing resources by name or get the first match)
- `SqlServerProvider` ✓ (I use this for settings)
- `JsonResourceProvider` ✓ (I use this as a *translating* decorator for other resource-providers)
- `EnvironmentVariableProvider` ✓
- `SettingProvider` ✓ (I use this as a *translating* decorator for setting names)

I intend to add more later, e.g.:

- Registry
- Ftp (this one would require a new API for opening sessions)
- and many more...

---

It works surprisingly well. So, how do you like it and how would you improve it? The interfaces are very simple and some things are *hidden* inside `ResourceMetadata` but with an API for *everything* you must make some tradeoffs.

I'm particularly interested about what you think of the *wrapper* or decorator methods and parameter validation. I know, I used a couple `region`s but this is an absolute excepiton. I also wonder what you say about how I specify the *abilities* of each resource-provider via their `ResourceMetadata`.

I call it `IOnymous` and the complete code is as always on [GitHub](https://github.com/he-dev/reusable/tree/dev/Reusable.IOnymous/src) where you can take a look at all of it.